# attrs convert list[str] to list[float]

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing, python-attrs

Given the following scenario:

```
import attrs

@attrs.define(kw_only=True)
class A:
    values: list[float] = attrs.field(converter=float)

A(values=["1.1", "2.2", "3.3"])
```

which results in

```
*** TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'list'
```

Obviously it's due to providing the whole list to `float`, but is there a way to get attrs do the conversion on each element, without providing a custom converter function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `attrs` doesn't have a built-in option to switch conversion or validation to "element-wise", the way Pydantic's validators have the [`each_item`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#subclass-validators-and-each_item) parameter.

I know you specifically did not ask for a converter function, but I don't really see much of an issue in defining one that you can reuse as often as you need to. Here is one way to implement a converter for your specific case:

```py
from attrs import define, field
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import Any
 
def float_list(iterable: Iterable[Any]) -> list[float]:
    return [float(item) for item in iterable]

@define
class A:
    values: list[float] = field(converter=float_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(values=["1.1", "2.2", "3.3"])
    print(a)
```

It is not much of a difference to your example using `converter=float`.

The output is of course `A(values=[1.1, 2.2, 3.3])`.

---

You could even have your own generic converter factory for arbitrary convertible item types:

```py
from attrs import define, field
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterable
from typing import Any, TypeAlias, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
ItemConv: TypeAlias = Callable[[Any], T]
ListConv: TypeAlias = Callable[[Iterable[Any]], list[T]]

def list_of(item_type: ItemConv[T]) -> ListConv[T]:
    def converter(iterable: Iterable[Any]) -> list[T]:
        return [item_type(item) for item in iterable]
    return converter

@define
class B:
    foo: list[float] = field(converter=list_of(float))
    bar: list[int] = field(converter=list_of(int))
    baz: list[bool] = field(converter=list_of(bool))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B(
        foo=range(0, 10, 2),
        bar=["1", "2", 3.],
        baz=(-1, 0, 100),
    )
    print(b)
```

Output: `B(foo=[0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0], bar=[1, 2, 3], baz=[True, False, True])`

The only downside to that approach is that the `mypy` plugin for `attrs` (for some reason) can not handle this type of converter function and will complain, unless you add `# type: ignore[misc]` to the field definition in question.

Comment: Thanks, glad to have seen your generic converter approach. It shows me a side of python that I'm still not that familiar with

Comment: Does this type check with mypy? I get the following error: `Unsupported converter, only named functions, types and lambdas are currently supported`; mypy-1.5.1

Comment: @ThomasHilger I think you might have missed the last paragraph in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [cattrs](https://cattrs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is a companion library for attrs for transforming data.

So after a `pip install cattrs`:

```py
from functools import partial

import attrs

from cattrs import structure


@attrs.define(kw_only=True)
class A:
    values: list[float] = attrs.field(converter=partial(structure, cl=list[float]))


print(A(values=["1.1", "2.2", "3.3"]))
```